# Create a step by step click through HTML5/Javascript graphics for an education tool

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating an educational tool in HTML5 and Javascript to help users understand how voting algorithms work. I will be stepping through each step by diplaying some sort of graphics or animation. I am essentially creating an HTML version of this: http://www.chrisgates.net/irv/votesequence.html

Any ideas how i could go about doing this? I have been experimenting with various Canvas packages which draw graphs and stuff but nothing that would help to step through an tutorial.

Comment: This is too broad a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence what you want to do is to change the content of some HTML element based on clicks on buttons or other HTMLelements.

You don't really need to use a Canvas for that. Of course, if you want to really make everything animated with lines slowly extending etc, using Canvas makes things a lot easier.

When just using Javascript you could create hidden elements with your desired data in them, and show them when somebody clicked on a certain button(wich could be, but doesn't have to be inside one of the other hidden elements).

If you réally want to use Canvas, I suggest you to look at [Cake.js](http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/) This is a Vector-based Canvas Library, wich could create results similar to the flash tool in your link. To use it is pretty straightforward, and there is a (small) wiki explaining the basic things.